# Matlab: Add Milliseconds to time vector hh:mm:ss

Tags: matlab, datetime, time

I have a matrix

```
M = 
hh:mm:ss ms
'12:00:01' 1
'12:00:02' 2
'12:00:03' 3
'12:00:04' 4
'12:00:05' 5
```

Now I want to add the array of milliseconds `ms` to my time vector. Like

```
   N = 
    hh:mm:ss
    '12:00:01.001'
    '12:00:02.002'
    '12:00:03.003'
    '12:00:04.004'
    '12:00:05.005'
```

How can I do this? What I tried was:

```
for k=1:length(M)
    t1 = datenum(M{k,1},'HH:MM:SS');
    c = num2str(M{k,2});
    t2 = datenum(c,'FFF');
    time = t1+t2;
    N{k,1} = datestr(time,'HH:MM:SS.FFF');
end
```

But this did not do the job right. What I get is:

```
N = 
hh:mm:ss
'12:00:01.100'
'12:00:02.200'
'12:00:03.300'
...
'12:00:04.100'
'12:00:05.110'
'12:00:05.120'
```

I think this problem is simple to solve. But at the moment I just do not know how solve it.

Answer (score 2):

It's a string formatting problem.

In your code, instead of

```
c = num2str(M{k,2});
```

use

```
c = sprintf('%03d',M{k,2});
```

In the above usage, `sprintf` pads zeros in front of a string if it's less than 3 characters long.

Comment: My string goes from 1:10000. So it is more than 3 character long. How can I handle this with your code? Thank you!

Comment: To format numbers into 5 digit string, you can use sprintf('%05d',M{k,2}); but it won't help here because there are only one thousand millisecond in a second and `datenum` will only take three characters anyways. You should turn anything larger than 1000 millisecond into second + millisecond.